# Linearize or approximate a square root constraint

Tags: linear-programming, nonlinear-programming, constraint, linearization

I encounter a nonlinear constraint that contains the square root of a sum of integer variables. Of course one could use nonlinear solvers and techniques; but I like linear programming. Are there any standard results on linearizing or approximating a square root of the sum of integer variables?

For example, the constraints look like this:

$$\sqrt{\sum_{i \in \mathcal{I}} a_{ij}x_{ij}  }  \leq \theta_j, \quad \quad \forall j \in \mathcal{J}$$

where $x_{ij} \in \{0,1\}$ are binary variables, $\theta_j \in \mathbb{R}$ are continuous variables, and $a_{ij} \geq 0$ are parameters.  $\mathcal{I}$ and $\mathcal{J}$ are any given sets of polynomial size.

Of course, this constraint is part of a larger MIP, but as I am curious to general methods and results regarding this constraint I believe it not to be of interest to post it here.

Comment: Could you add some additional information about the constraint (maybe a simplified version)? Is the constraint convex?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This can be handled as an MISOCP, Mixed-Integer Second Order Cone problem. The leading commercial MILP solvers can also handle MISOCP.

Specifically, due to $x_{ij}$ being binary, $x_{ij}^2 = x_{ij}$. Therefore, the left-hand side is the two-norm of the vector over $i \in I$ having elements $\sqrt{a_{ij}} x_{ij}$.

I don't know whether this is the best way to handle this constraint, but it is a way, and it is "exact".

Comment: I agree with this answer. To add to this: if you *really* want to solve an LP rather than an SOCP, you can approximate the SOCP constraint with a polynomial number of LP constraints, as discussed [here](https://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/abs/10.1287/moor.26.2.193.10561). AFAIK it's generally understood that solving the problem as one SOCP is faster.

Comment: I like this answer a lot. To add: for a good reference on modeling SOCP, see [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0024-3795(98)10032-0).

Comment: Could you expand on where the term $x_{i,j}^2$ comes from. If taking squares in both sides, aren't we missing the cross terms $x_{ij}x_{k,j}$?

Comment: @Daniel Duque If $x \in \{0,1\}$ then you can simply replace $x$ by $x^2$. This is due to the fact that $0^2 = 0$ and $1^2 = 1$ and thus $x^2 = x$ for all permitted values.

Comment: I see now, thanks.

Comment: Is there a book describing the theory about SOCP?

Comment: @Alexandre Frias "Convex Optimization"  by Boyd and Vandenberghe https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/ . Also, the MOSEK Modeling Cookbook (chapter 3) https://docs.mosek.com/MOSEKModelingCookbook-letter.pdf

Answer (score 4):

Please also have a look at the very [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3203652) in math.stackexchange. As @Mark L. Stone mentioned in his answer, all you need is a second-order cone model to solve your problem.

Comment: Please avoid link-only answers.

Answer (score 3):

To linearize that constraint *as it is* can be hard since it is non-convex. Assuming you still want to do that, you would need to introduce binary variables that allow you characterize the function.

Focusing on a single $j$, let first define $w_j=\sum\limits_{I\in I}a_{i,j} x_{i,j}$, with $w_j\geq 0$ and assume you have a bound on such that $w_j\leq UB_j$. Now let $n$ be the number of pieces (linear inequalities) you want to use to describe $\sqrt{w_j}$, and for each piece, let $m_{k,j}$ and $b_{k,j}$ be the slope and intercept of the $k$th piece of the $j$th constraint for $k=1,\ldots,n$, which are tangent lines of $\theta_j=\sqrt{w_j}$ at (finite) points $w_{k,j}\in[0,UB_j]$ (these are the breakpoints in the $w_j$ space), $k=1,\ldots,n+1$. Since the constraint are not convex, only one piece can be "on" in an optimal solution, hence, let $\lambda_{k,j}\in\{0,1\}$ be a binary variable that is one if the piece is "on" for constraint $j\in J$, zero otherwise. Putting all together,

- Choose only one piece for crt $j$: $$\sum\limits_{k=1}^n{\lambda_{k,j}}=1 \quad\forall j\in J$$
- $w_j$ need to be in the right interval if you choose piece $k$ $$-M(1-\lambda_{k,j}) + w_{k,j}\le w_j \le w_{k+1,j} + M(1-\lambda_{k,j}) \quad \forall j \in J,\,k=1,\ldots,n$$
- Definition of $w_j$: $$w_j = \sum\limits_{I\in I}a_{i,j} x_{i,j} \quad\forall j \in J$$
- This is the linearized constraint, where $\theta_j$ is greater or equal to the piece that is selected: $$\theta_j\ge m_{k,j} w_j + b_{k,j} - M(1-\lambda_{k,j}) \quad\forall j\in J,\, k=1,\ldots,n$$

As a side note, you have to choose the breakpoints upfront. A plot of $\theta_j\ge \sqrt{w_j}$ (for a single $j$, this a 2D-plot) can help to clarify the linearization.

If your constraints are convex (e.g., the inequality is $\ge$ or you treat it as an SOCP as described in the answer above), then you could implement [Kelley's cutting-plane](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0108053?journalCode=smjmap.1)<sup>1</sup> method which is an outer approximation method. Those cuts are not cuts in the integer programming sense, so don't add them as cuts. Rather, in B&B add them as lazy constraints. Alternatively, if the MIP is easy to solve, generate a single (Kelley's) cut at a time an re-optimize.

---

<sub>Reference</sub>

<sub>[1] Kelley, J. E., Jr. (1960). The Cutting-Plane Method For Solving Convex Programs. *Journal of the Society for Industrial and Applied Mathematics*. 8(4):703-712.</sub>

Comment: Is all this really needed? The square root function is concave, so you could just use a series of cutting planes: linearisation of square root at $\sum\limits_i a_i x_i = \text{sth}\le\theta_j$; with enough cutting planes, you are drawing an approximation that is good enough. (Or you can use an iterative process to add new cutting planes, to reduce the total number of constraints.) I guess that's what https://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/abs/10.1287/moor.26.2.193.10561 does.

Comment: It is necessary due to the sense of the inequality. In the way it’s written in the question, that constraint defines a non-convex feasible region. If the inequality is the other way around, then it would be much easier as it would be a convex feasible region (ignoring the integrality of x).

Answer (score 3):

You can manipulate this inequality as follows

$$\sqrt{\sum_{i \in \mathcal{I}} a_{ij}x_{ij}  }  \leq \theta_j, \quad \quad \forall j \in \mathcal{J}$$

$$\sum_{i \in \mathcal{I}} a_{ij}x_{ij}  \leq \theta_j^2, \quad \quad \forall j \in \mathcal{J}$$

Now, you need to linearize $\theta_j^2$ using [McCormick Envelopes](https://optimization.mccormick.northwestern.edu/index.php/McCormick_envelopes). To do this, assume $-M_j\leq \theta_j \leq M_j$ and consider $w_j=\theta_j^2$

$$
\begin{align}
0\leq (\theta_j + M_j)(\theta_j + M_j) & \implies & -w_j - 2M_j\theta \leq M_j^2\\
0\leq (M_j - \theta_j)(M_j - \theta_j) & \implies & -w_j + 2M_j\theta \leq M_j^2\\
0\leq (\theta_j + M_j)(M_j - \theta_j) & \implies & w_j \leq M_j^2\\
\end{align}
$$

The final set of constraints is

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i \in \mathcal{I}} a_{ij}x_{ij}  \leq w_j, \quad \quad \forall j \in \mathcal{J}\\
-w_j - 2M_j\theta_j \leq M_j^2, \quad \quad \forall j \in \mathcal{J}\\
-w_j + 2M_j\theta_j \leq M_j^2, \quad \quad \forall j \in \mathcal{J}\\
0 \leq w_j \leq M_j^2, \quad \quad \forall j \in \mathcal{J}\\
-M_j \leq \theta_j \leq M_j, \quad \quad \forall j \in \mathcal{J}\\
\end{align}
$$

OBS: Verify my counts, please.

Comment: McCormick envelopes provide a relaxation for real variables.

Comment: is the value of $M_j$ critical for any reason? Does it have to be a tight value? Assuming, $\theta_j\in \mathbb{R}^+$, can we reorganize ``the final set of constraints" (assume the numbering to be 1–5) as follows? Keep (1), (3), and (4); remove (2) because $\theta_j\in\mathbb{R}^+$ means $w_j,~M_j\in\mathbb{R}$ which makes (2) redundant; condense (5) to $\theta_j\leq M_j$.