# Linearizing the square root of two binary summations

Tags: linearization, nonconvex-programming

My question is similar to [this one](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/1052/linearize-or-approximate-a-square-root-constraint) though a bit more complicated. Though my question also includes indices, I am removing them to ease readability.

Let binary variables $x,y\in\{0,1\}$, non-negative continuous variable $z\in\mathbb{R}^+$ and the parameter $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}^+$. Is there a way to linearize the below equality constraint?

$$\displaystyle z=\sqrt{\lambda\left(x+y\right)}$$

Can we benefit from the fact that $\alpha=x+y$, where $\alpha \in \{0,1,2\}$ and write additional constraints?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For $j\in\{0,1,2\}$, introduce binary variable $w_j$ to indicate whether $x+y=j$, and then impose the following linear constraints:
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=0}^2 w_j &= 1 \\
\sum_{j=0}^2 j\cdot w_j &= x+y \\
\sqrt{\lambda}\sum_{j=0}^2 \sqrt{j}\cdot w_j &= z
\end{align}

Comment: I posted and indexed version of the problem [here] (https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/3568/linearizing-the-square-root-of-binary-summations) and I cannot ensure whether I correctly apply it or not. Can you please give it a hand?